# Building a select with optgroup from a SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have the following table:

___Titles

```
| TIT_Id | TIT_en | TIT_Popularity |
| 1      | Sir    | High           |
| 2      | Madam  | High           |
| 2      | Emir   | Low            |
```

How can I have this select ?

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="High">
    <option value='1'>Sir</option>
    <option value='2'>Madam</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Low">
    <option value='3'>Emir</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

I tried:

```
SELECT TIT_Id, TIT_en FROM ___Titles
GROUP BY TIT_Popularity
ORDER BY TIT_en ASC
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could just process the array from the selected db (since the queries are not inside the question), and just build them and reorder them on that newly created array (provided the popularity is just high/low). Consider this example:

```
<?php

// dummy data, since no values are provided on the question
$values_from_db = array(
    array('TIT_Id' => 3, 'TIT_en' => 'Emir', 'TIT_Popularity' => 'Low'),
    array('TIT_Id' => 4, 'TIT_en' => 'Test', 'TIT_Popularity' => 'Low'),
    array('TIT_Id' => 1, 'TIT_en' => 'Sir', 'TIT_Popularity' => 'High'),
    array('TIT_Id' => 2, 'TIT_en' => 'Madam', 'TIT_Popularity' => 'High'),

);

$sorted_values = array();
foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value) {
    $sorted_values[$value['TIT_Popularity']][] = array(
        'TIT_Id' => $value['TIT_Id'],
        'TIT_en' => $value['TIT_en'],
    );
}

ksort($sorted_values);

?>

<select name="whatever">
    <option selected disabled>Select Value</option>
<?php foreach($sorted_values as $key => $value): ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $element['TIT_Id']; ?>"><?php echo $element['TIT_en']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>            
    </optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this.  Fetch your results using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ___Titles ORDER BY TIT_Popularity;
```

This will essentially group your results together by their `TIT_Popularity`.  You can then iterate over them like this:

```
echo "<select>\n";

$currentGroup = null;
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    // start a new optgroup
    if( $currentGroup == null || $result->TIT_Popularity != $currentGroup ) {
        // end the previous group
        if( $currentGroup != null ) {
            echo "</optgroup\n>";
        }

        // start a new group
        echo "<optgroup label='{$result->TIT_Popularity}'>\n";

        $currentGroup = $result->TIT_Popularity;
    }

    echo "<option value='{$result->TIT_Id}'>{$result->TIT_en}</option>\n";
}

// end the last opt group
if( $currentGroup != null ) echo "</optgroup>\n";


echo "</select>\n";
```

Comment: Then you don't have any elements in `$results`.  Try `var_dump($results)` to see what's in there.  If nothing, try running your query manually to see if you get any results that way and also check if your query is giving you errors.

Comment: The var_dump game me: 
array(3) { ["TIT_Id"]=> string(1) "1" ["TIT_fr"]=> string(8) "Monsieur" ["TIT_Popularity"]=> string(4) "High" }

Comment: That's one record, not a collection of records.  `$results` in this example would be all of the records.  You can replace the `foreach` with something like `while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($resultsIdentifier)) {` or however you've structured your program.

Comment: This answer should give you a general idea of how to solve your problem.  You'll have to adapt it to fit your exact situation.

Comment: I'm using PDO: $results = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Then replace the `foreach` with `while($result = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) {`  Or, if you want to use an associative array, just change all of the object calls on $result to associative array calls.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. But how does this process happens?  How it echos option group only once if it is associated with every option. ? Plz explain. .

Comment: @MujahedAKAS It only outputs a new optgroup when the value of `TIT_Popularity` changes.  So the first time it changes, a new one is output, and another won't be output until the `TIT_Popularity` changes again.  So, as long as `TIT_Popularity` stays the same, all entries will be output in that same optgroup.  Just reason through the logic of the `if` statement until it makes sense.